# How could Professor-X, Scott and Jean be alive in the X-Men: Days of Future Past

Tags: marvel, x-men

Before there was the attempt to send back Wolverine to the past by 50 years, during the battle Professor-X, Scott and Jean was alive, although they should have been dead? Can anyone give an explanation for that?
They died at the end of the last X-Men as far as I remember.

Comment: If I'll have more time I'll specify it in more details...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [post-credits scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSkn3KYwmtc) from *X-Men: The Last Stand* strongly hints that Professor Xavier survived by planting his consciousness in a comatose man. Wikipedia claims that in the DVD commentary the writers indicate that the man is a twin brother of Charles, explaining why they look exactly alike. I've heard that claim many times, but I don't own the DVD, so I can't check. Whether it's his twin brother-- or whether he had plastic surgery or something all that matters is that the Professor survives.

But I'm afraid you're a bit confused when it comes to Cyclops and Jean. [The opening battle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiRUCmj5gO8) contains Shadowcat, Bishop, Blink, Sunspot, and Colossus, but not them. Their only appearances in *Days of Future Past* occur after Logan creates a new timeline.

Comment: Looks like someone indeed manage to understand the "unclear" question.